# How do I prepend variable to open file stream when using split to create csv's?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, aws-cli

I have a bash file that takes a large csv and splits the csv into smaller csv's based on this blog https://medium.com/swlh/automatic-s3-file-splitter-620d04b6e81c. It works well as it is fast never downloading the csv's which is great for a lambda. The csv's after they split do not have headers only the originating csv. This is problem for me since I am not able to read with apache pyspark a set of files one with header row and many other files without header rows.

I want to add a header row to each csv written.

What the code does

INFILE

- "s3//test-bucket/test.csv"

OUTFILES - split into 300K lines

- "s3//dest-test-bucket/test.00.csv"
- "s3//dest-test-bucket/test.01.csv"
- "s3//dest-test-bucket/test.02.csv"
- "s3//dest-test-bucket/test.03.csv"

Original code that works

```bash
LINECOUNT=300000
INFILE=s3://"${S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME}"
OUTFILE=s3://"${DEST_S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME%%.*}"

FILES=($(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | split -d -l ${LINECOUNT} --filter "aws s3 cp - \"${OUTFILE}_\$FILE.csv\"  | echo \"\$FILE.csv\""))
```

This was my attempt to add a variable to outgoing file stream, but it did not work.

```bash
LINECOUNT=300000
INFILE=s3://"${S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME}"
OUTFILE=s3://"${DEST_S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME%%.*}"

HEADER=$(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | head -n 1)

FILES=($(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | split -d -l ${LINECOUNT} --filter "echo ${HEADER}; aws s3 cp - \"${OUTFILE}_\$FILE.csv\"  | echo \"\$FILE.csv\""))
```

Attempt 2:

```bash
LINECOUNT=300000
INFILE=s3://"${S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME}"
OUTFILE=s3://"${DEST_S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME%%.*}"

HEADER=$(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | head -n 1)

FILES=($(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | split -d -l ${LINECOUNT} --filter "{ echo -n ${HEADER}; aws s3 cp - \"${OUTFILE}_\$FILE.csv\"; } | echo \"\$FILE.csv\""))
```

[AWS documentation states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects-copy)

> You can use the dash parameter for file streaming to standard input (stdin) or standard output (stdout).

I don't know if this is even possible with a open file stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. I think you are only missing the `cat` aspect of adding the header.

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/split-file-with-header) article shows one way to split a file and provide the header using `split` command and `filter` arguments.

Using that snip and applying it to the code above seems to work. Notice that the 2 commands inside the curly braces are `echo ${HEADER}` and `cat`. The first, `echo` creates the header on stdout and then the second, `cat` will pipe `aws cp` stdin to stdout which is the input to `aws cp -` creating the new file on S3.

```bash
HEADER='"Name", "Team", "Position", "Height(inches)", "Weight(lbs)", "Age"'

aws s3 cp ${INFILE} - | split -d -l ${LINECOUNT} --filter "{ \[ "\$FILE" != "x00" \] && echo ${HEADER} ; cat; } | aws s3 cp - \"${OUTFILE}\${FILE}.csv\""
```

After running the command, I observed 3 new files and each file had the desired header.

```bash
head -n2 *.csv
==> x00.csv <==
"Name", "Team", "Position", "Height(inches)", "Weight(lbs)", "Age"
"Adam Donachie", "BAL", "Catcher", 74, 180, 22.99

==> x01.csv <==
Name, Team, Position, Height(inches), Weight(lbs), Age
"John Rheinecker", "TEX", "Starting Pitcher", 74, 230, 27.76

==> x02.csv <==
Name, Team, Position, Height(inches), Weight(lbs), Age
"Chase Utley", "PHI", "Second Baseman", 73, 183, 28.2
```

Comment: this works and is the solution to the question, but do you know how to not add the header to the first file. Which is my case already has the header so I do not want to add to header to that file also?

Comment: @vfrank66, good idea, I updated the answer to add a test of the FILE variable, when FILE is the first file name the header is not added.